# DB error using updateObject or Store after upgrading to Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, development, database

I am a component developer and now I am migrating my component to Joomla 4.x.

In Joomla 3.x I could do code like:

```
$row= new stdClass();
$row->id = "2";
$row->user_id = "";
$row->anythind = "foo bar";

// Insert the object into the user profile table.
$result = JFactory::getDbo()->updateObject('#__test_table', $row, 'id');
```

Note that user_id is an empty string but in the DB is an integer type column. But once executed the DB value of user_id would be cero.

After upgrading to Joomla 4.4.3 the same code gives this error:

"1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column `database`.`#__test_table`.`user_id`  at row 1"

Does not accept an empty string for a column of integers.

I have also tried it with the JTable::store() method and I have the same result.

With dozens of administration forms it is literally impossible to force all integer fields to have a zero and not simply leave them blank.

I appreciate any help you can give me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the point of this question since you already know the answer. You are using a string value for an integer column. This is clearly incorrect even if it worked before. The reason this did work in J3 is because the database driver explicitly used non-strict SQL mode. In J4 the driver uses `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO`, `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` modes. And these are still much looser than MySQL's defaults (`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`, `NO_ZERO_DATE`, `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO` and `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` on MySQL 8). In the future, SQL modes in Joomla should only get stricter.

Furthermore, adding data filtering and validation, and using sane defaults, is not "literally impossible". It's necessary for a secure and reliable application and ideally should be done from the beginning.